# Como o Django cria e verifica tokens para resetar senha?

Tags: django, autenticação, token

Considerando um modelo para resetar senha já implementado pelo Django, nas seguintes views:

- django.contrib.auth.password_reset
- django.contrib.auth.password_reset_done
- django.contrib.auth.password_reset_confirm
- django.contrib.auth.password_reset_complete

Na view "*django.contrib.auth.password_reset*" é gerado um token passado como parametro de url para a view "*django.contrib.auth.password_reset_confirm*".

Sobre este token, não achei nada a respeito na documentação do Django e também não consegui entender o código fonte, contudo tenho as seguintes perguntas:

1. Como ele é gerado e verificado?
2. O token é persistido no banco de dados e vinculado ao usuário, ou é gerado apenas uma hash da id ?
3. Utilizando este metodo pode ser gerado tokens para outras utilidades, como por exemplo para ativar uma conta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara excelente pergunta!

Vamos lá, segundo a [documentação do Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/views/):

Existem 4 views para o reset de password:

```
# - password_reset envia o email
# - password_reset_done mostra uma mensagem de sucesso para o envio do email
# - password_reset_confirm checa a url e pergunta por uma nova senha
# - password_reset_complete mostra uma mensagem de sucesso para todo o processo
```

As views password_reset e password_reset_confirm utilizam a mesma classe para gerar e conferir o token. `django.contrib.auth.tokens.default_token_generator`.

**1. Como ele é gerado e verificado?**

Olhando no link da documentação é possível reparar que o django utiliza a seguinte classe para a geração do token from `django.contrib.auth.tokens.default_token_generator`.

Buscando por essa [classe](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py) no projeto do github é possível verificar que o token é gerado de acordo com o usuário e o timestamp.

Removendo os comentários do código se tem:

```
def make_token(self, user):
    return self._make_token_with_timestamp(user, self._num_days(self._today()))

def _make_token_with_timestamp(self, user, timestamp):
    ts_b36 = int_to_base36(timestamp)
    hash = salted_hmac(
        self.key_salt,
        self._make_hash_value(user, timestamp),
    ).hexdigest()[::2]
    return "%s-%s" % (ts_b36, hash)

def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
    login_timestamp = '' if user.last_login is None else user.last_login.replace(microsecond=0, tzinfo=None)
    return (
        six.text_type(user.pk) + user.password +
        six.text_type(login_timestamp) + six.text_type(timestamp)
    )
```

Verificando esse código e o que está no github (não irei incluir tudo pois acredito ser desnecessário) nós podemos concluir que o token formado é gerado a partir do `timestamp+"-"+hash`

Onde:

```
#timestamp = conversao numero de dias desde 01/01/2001 para a base 36.
#hash = user.pk + user.password + user.last_login + timestamp
```

O fato do código utilizar `six.text_type` se deve ao fato de que foi definido um padrão de `str` para o Python3 e `unicode` para as outras versões, como se pode ver no próprio código da classe `six`.

```
if PY3:
    string_types = str,
    integer_types = int,
    class_types = type,
    text_type = str
    binary_type = bytes

    MAXSIZE = sys.maxsize
else:
    string_types = basestring,
    integer_types = (int, long)
    class_types = (type, types.ClassType)
    text_type = unicode
    binary_type = str
```

**2. O token é persistido no banco de dados e vinculado ao usuário, ou é gerado apenas uma hash da id ?**

Como é possível verificar no código do projeto, o token não é persistido e sim gerado e confirmado no momento de acesso. Como demonstrado na primeira questão.

**3. Utilizando este metodo pode ser gerado tokens para outras utilidades, como por exemplo para ativar uma conta?**

Sim, você pode aproveitar a classe `django.contrib.auth.tokens.default_token_generator` para poder fazer a geração e validação do token, mas terá que implementar as suas próprias views.

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu tinha visto este código no GitHub porém não entendi como era a validação uma vez que não era persistido um código para comparação, então resumindo e semelhante a maneira que ele criptografa o password, apenas usa o mesmo mecanismo de criptografia e compara as chaves ?

Comment: Esta documentação e da versão 1.8 , é valido para versões mais recentes ?