# Existe algum risco em utilizar o gerador de Tokens do Django em diferentes serviços?

Tags: django, hash, token

Supondo que ja estou utilizando a biblioteca   `django.contrib.auth.tokens.default_token_generator`
 gerando tokens para resetar a senha de um usuário, e 
 queira utilizar o mesmo    método para ativar o usuário, ou para qualquer outro   serviço semelhante, existem    os seguintes riscos?

1. Revelar detalhes indesejados para o usuário como id ou a hash da senha persistida em banco;
2. Assim que gerado um token 'X' em determinada ação, como por exemplo, resetar a senha, o usuário poder utilizar este mesmo token para outra ação, como por exemplo, ativar usuário;
3. Assim que gerado um novo token para o usuário, os tokens anteriores do mesmo usuário continuarem ativos.

   Apesar de esclarecerem parcialmente minhas dúvidas [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/133687/como-o-django-cria-e-verifica-tokens-para-resetar-senha/133692#133692) ainda não sei dizer como um token permanece ativado ou desativado sem a persistência em um banco de dados, seria através da atualização do campo `last_login` do usuário?

   Contudo gostaria de entender definitivamente a lógica por trás deste método para entender os riscos e benefícios em produção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar:

```
import binascii
import os

numero_de_caracteres = 15
token = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(numero_de_caracteres))
print(token)
```

O código acima gera uma string aleatoriamente com 15 caracteres e armazena na variável token. Para definir o número de caracteres basta modificar o valor da variável numero_de_caracteres.